# Pkg package setting up name and icon for executable file

Tags: javascript

I am using `node` with `pkg` package. I use it for creating executable file for mac and windows. Problem is that if I compile it I get files with node icon and node or file folder structure as a name. How can I change both name and icon of executable files? Is it possible? I tried to find it in [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) but I couldn't find it.